# PGP key manager

Tags: evolution, gnupg

I have 2 Vmware machines on player..

First is Ubuntu with email client Evolution
I have generated key in seahorse on email a@xxx.com

Second is Windows with email client Thunderbird
I have generated key with enigmail on email b@xxx.com

What I want to do is to send encrypted and signed emails from a@xxx.com to b@xxx.com and reply to a@xxx.com from b@xxx.com

With enigmail I have downloaded public key b@xxx.com and I can see it.

Problem is very simple: When I send email from thunderbird a@xxx.com signed and encrypted to b@xxx.com it works fine and I can see message.

But when I try to reply from b@xxx.com (evolution mail client) to a@xxx.com (thunderbird mail client) I get error:

: Because "gpg: using subkey xxxxxxxx instead of primary key xxxxxxxxxx gpg: No trust check due to '--trust-model always' option gpg: : skipped: No public key gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key ", you may need to select different mail options.

**problem is that I cant reply from b@xxx.com to a@xxx.com of error ^^^^**

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you edit and rephrase it to include: which steps you exactly took to export and import the key, what messages have been printed, and how exactly you're trying to send an email? Also, are you aware of the difference between signing and encryption, the public and private key and finally which key is required for which operation?

Comment: Hello Jens Erat,

Problem is only one... When using windows thunderbird client email (a) to send signed mail to ubuntu evolution client email (b) it works fine!

But when I try to send mail from ubuntu evolution client email (b) to (a) I got this error : 

Because "gpg: using subkey xxxxxxxx instead of primary key xxxxxxxxxx
gpg: No trust check due to '--trust-model always' option
gpg: <b>: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
", you may need to select different mail options.

Comment: Please go through my comment again and try to answer all the details I requested. All of them provide very basic information required to answer your question, which is still lacking important information. Furthermore, I still have massive trouble making sense out of what you've written, especially the fourth paragraph. Then, in your fifth paragraph, you write you can't improt keys from Thunderbird to GPA -- both of them should rely on the same key store, as they both just interface the command line GnuPG application. Finally, how many key pairs have you created for which mail addresses?

Comment: @JensErat - I have corrected my problem.

Comment: Have you "added your trust" to the key (i.e. signed it) already? I had a similar issue a while ago: Sending an encrypted mail to "b@" from my account of "a@" always failed with that message. I then went to my GPG Manager on the A account, and (temp-)signed the key of "b@" – et voila, it worked. // By "temp-signing" (I don't remember the correct term) I mean to only sign it *locally*, so the trust wouldn't be exported if you decide to upload the public key. You can also "fully sign it" if you know it's the right one :)